# How to show and hide an existing JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am doing some basic tests to understand how Java Swing works.

I have a test application which consist of three fully independent windows (JFrames):

1. Main Menu
2. Asset Window 1
3. Asset Window 2

The **Main Menu** has a JButton which will show/hide **Asset Window 1** (*a1*).

This is the main class to launch all windows:

```java
package test1;

import test1.AssetList.AssetList;
import test1.MainMenu.MainMenu;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainMenu m = new MainMenu();
                AssetList a1 = new AssetList();
                AssetList a2 = new AssetList();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the class with the **Asset Window** JFrame:

```java
package test1.AssetList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class AssetList extends JFrame {

    public AssetList() {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Asset list");
        this.getContentPane().add(label);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(false);

    }

}
```

This is the class for the **MainMenu** JFrame:

```java
package test1.MainMenu;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MainMenu extends JFrame {

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Main Menu");
    JButton button = new JButton("Asset");  

    public MainMenu() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.getContentPane().add(label);
        this.getContentPane().add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ButtonAssetListener());

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

This is the class for the **Asset Window Button** JButton listener:

```java
package test1.MainMenu;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ButtonAssetListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

        System.out.println("CLICK!");
        /* PSEUDOCODE
        if(a1 from Test1.isVisible()==true) {
           a1 from Test1.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            a1 from Test1.setVisible(true);
        }
        */
    }

}
```

How can I retrieve the **a1** instance from **ButtonAssetListener** in order to toggle its visibility?
Is there a better alternative to structure this kind of multiple windows application in Java Swing?

Comment: You should not be using multiple frames. If you want multiple windows then use a JDialog for the child window to the main parent frame.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for your comments. I will read the post throughly

Comment: Even when using multiple JDialogs as child windows among a main parent frame, the question of accessing other windows would be still there.

Comment: @AndrewThompson after reading the post I am not 100% clear if I shall go for multiple JFrames or not. My app will be multi monitor and fully customizable layout must be allowed. Each window will be autonomous and loosely related to other windows. I will probably do a test with both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the instance you want to hide to the button listener.

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AssetList a1 = new AssetList();
                AssetList a2 = new AssetList();
                MainMenu m = new MainMenu(a1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Make your main menu take in a component which it will show and hide.

```
public class MainMenu extends JFrame {

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Main Menu");
    JButton button = new JButton("Asset");  

    public MainMenu(JComponent assetList) {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.getContentPane().add(label);
        this.getContentPane().add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ButtonAssetListener(assetList));

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Then modify your your button asset listener to take in a component which it will then show or hide.

```
public class ButtonAssetListener implements ActionListener{

    private JComponent component;

    public ButtonAssetListener(JComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(component.isVisible()) {
           component.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            component.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was recommended (outside stack overflow) to use a class with JFrames as static resources. Class can be instantiated across different entities and JFrames can be accessed. I was adviced to use this solution in a single-user application. Moving arguments across different classes can be cumbersome when dealing with a large number of windows.

Comment: @M.E. I would agree with that in general. However in your case you have 1 or more "AssetList" frames where in many applications you have 1 WinMain type class. This solution is just one way of doing it, maybe instead you want to do something with a registry of sorts where windows are registered then your MainMenu can look at that registry and see whats there. Might be a better way for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for further commenting on your answer. As part of the recommendation the registry method you are mentioning was raised. As of now I am doing just very basic steps as I need to learn Swing (I have used other widget frameworks in other languages in the past, but not Swing), but I will move into sort kind of registry if that makes sense (which is probably the case as the number of windows will be variable). I will incorporate all that gradually.